# How to integrate Paypal Express Checkout with the Magento API

Tags: api, payment-methods, paypal-express

I am building a custom store using the Magento APIs. Everything upto shipping is working, but I'm stuck at billing.

- I have enabled the **Check/Money Order** payment method and thats working fine. But I need to integrate Paypal Express Checkout in my custom store.
- I have configured Paypal Express Checkout option as needed in the **Payment Methods** configuration section.
- The ***cart_payment.list*** API call is only returning 'Check/Money Order' as the available payment method.
- The Paypal Express Checkout option is not returned.

Is it possible to somehow list the Paypal Express Checkout option as well in the ***cart_payment.list*** API call response?

`[ { code: 'checkmo', title: 'Check / Money order', ccTypes: null } ]`

As you can see, it returns *Check/Money Order* with a code **checkmo**. I need to know the code for Express Checkout.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express` class:

```
protected $_code  = Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS;
```

Then from `Mage_Paypal_Model_Config` class:

```
const METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS = 'paypal_express';
```

So the code for paypal express is (surprisingly) `paypal_express`.